# Different titleformat style for different numberless chapters

Tags: titlesec

I want each numberless "chapter" page to have a different style for the title. Please see:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\titlerule[1pt]%
\vspace{1pt}%
\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\Huge}


\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\titlerule[1pt]%
\vspace{1pt}%
\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\LARGE{something for index only}}
{1pc}
{\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\Huge}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{My first chapter}
dummy text

\chapter{My second chapter}
ciao
\end{document}
```

With the previous code I have:

1. a title style for normal chapter pages
2. a title style for **all** numberless chapter pages: index page, bibliography page, etc.

I want to have multiple numberless styles, one for the index page, one for the bibliography page, etc. How do I add more than two styles?

Comment: You can give `\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}...` anywhere and at any time; the current style will be used for the next `\chapter*` commands until a new declaration is issued. But why should you do it?

Comment: @egreg In my style (the one posted was a random one taken from the titlesec documentation), I have some space which is filled with the number in case of the numbered chapters and is empty for index and bibliography. I want to place a symbol for the index (like a dotted list) and another one for the bibliography (like a book). Anyway, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can place `\titleformat` instructions anywhere and the format declaration will hold for all subsequent chapters, until a new `\titleformat` instruction comes along.

Probably the best is to define all formats in the preamble, hiding them in macros. For instance

```
\newcommand{\tocformat}{%
  \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
    {\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
    {\titlerule[1pt]%
     \vspace{1pt}%
     \titlerule
     \vspace{1pc}%
     \LARGE something for TOC only}%%%% <---- \LARGE doesn't take an argument
    {1pc}
    {\titlerule
     \vspace{1pc}%
     \Huge}%
}

\newcommand{\bibliographyformat}{%
  \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
    {\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
    {\titlerule[1pt]%
     \vspace{1pt}%
     \titlerule
     \vspace{1pc}%
     \LARGE something for bibliography only}
    {1pc}
    {\titlerule
     \vspace{1pc}%
     \Huge}%
}
```

and issue `\tocformat` and `\bibliographyformat` in the document at the appropriate spots. This way you have a “centralized” place for all document setup.

The styling could be also automatized by incorporating the `\...format` commands in the relevant commands such as `\tableofcontents` via `\pretocmd` of `etoolbox` or similar patching macros.