# Hide titleformat in a macro when [explicit] is loaded

Tags: macros, sectioning, titlesec

This is a follow-up question to: [Different titleformat style for different numberless chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202451/different-titleformat-style-for-different-numberless-chapters)

I have something like the following macro:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\Huge\color{blue}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {%
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
      #1
    \end{minipage}
  }
```

The `#1` comes from the `[explicit]` option of the `titlesec` package. If I try to put the previous code inside another macro, like this:

```
\newcommand{\mycustomchapter}{
  \titleformat{\chapter}
   %...
}
```

compilations fails complaining about the argument.

Is it possible to hide the `\titleformat` macro in another macro when the `explicit` option is in place?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand{\mycustomchapter}{
  \titleformat{\chapter}
    {\normalfont\Huge\color{blue}}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {%
      \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
        #1
      \end{minipage}
    }
}

\begin{document}
  \mycustomchapter
  \chapter{My chapter}
  Bla bla bla 
\end{document}
```

Comment: We would appreciate a MWE ;-)

Comment: Yes, use `##1` instead of `#1`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer well it's same as before, but anyway here it is. Oh, nevermind, egreg was faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `##1` instead of `#1`. However, the `explicit` option is very rarely needed.

Better is like below: the last argument to `\titleformat` can end with a macro taking one argument, which will be fed the title.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\mycustomchapter}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}
    {\normalfont\Huge\color{blue}}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\mycustomchapterformat}%
}
\newcommand{\mycustomchapterformat}[1]{%
   \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
   #1
   \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}
  \mycustomchapter
  \chapter{My chapter}
  Bla bla bla 
\end{document}
```

[image]